# Absolute square in deriving Fourier transform variance

Tags: multivariable-calculus, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis

I'm having some trouble understanding how to derive the variance of the Fourier transform. This is for an image, i.e., it's a 2D transform.

The variance is $|\hat{I}(\xi,\eta)|^2$, the absolute square of the transform of the image; $\xi$ and $\eta$ are the coordinates in the frequency domain. 
$$\hat{I}(\xi,\eta) = \iint \mathbf{I}(x,y)\,e^{-i2\pi(x\xi + y\eta)}\,dx\,dy,$$
where $I(x, y)$ is the function representing the original image and the coordinates $x,y$ are in the spatial domain.

To calculate the variance, then, I want to do
$$|\hat{I}(\xi,\eta)|^2 = \iint \mathbf{I}(x,y)\,e^{-i2\pi(x\xi + y\eta)}\,dx\,dy\,\iint \bar{\mathbf{I}}(x,y)\,e^{i2\pi(x\xi + y\eta)}\,dx\,dy$$
$$= \iint \mathbf{I}(x,y)\,\bar{\mathbf{I}}(x,y)\,e^{i2\pi(x\xi + y\eta) \,- \,i2\pi(x\xi + y\eta)}\,dx\,dy$$

My questions are:

1. how do I deal with the conjugate of the function $\mathbf{I}$, i.e., $\bar{\mathbf{I}}(x,y)$? My inclination is that it doesn't change because all its values are real;
2. should the exponential term really cancel? As written now, it will go to $e^0 = 1$. What am I missing about conjugating functions?

The variance should be proportional to $\frac{1}{\xi^2 + \eta^2}$, which is why I suspect something is going wrong with the exponential term.

**Edited to clarify:**
The purpose of this is to show that the variance of $\hat{I}(\xi, \eta)$ is some scalar multiple of $\frac{1}{\xi^2 + \eta^2}$, i.e., 
$$
E_p[|\hat{I}(\xi, \eta)|^2] = s\frac{1}{\xi^2 + \eta^2}.
$$
I read [here](http://www.le.ac.uk/users/dsgp1/SIGNALS/FIVESTAT.pdf) that "the power of the process, which is expressed by its variance, is equal to the integral of the spectral density function over the interval $[−\pi, \pi]$".

The power is expressed as $|\hat{I}(\xi,\eta)|^2$. Shouldn't I just take the [absolute square](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbsoluteSquare.html) of $\hat{I}$?

Comment: I am guessing you are looking for Parseval's theorem? You went from the product of two integrals to a single integral above without any justification, the $(x,y)$ variables in each integral are different.

Comment: Hm. Indeed, I guess I assumed it worked the same as for adding/subtracting integrals. Would it be something like $$\iint \mathbf{I}(x,y)\,e^{i2\pi(x\xi + y\eta)} \Big[\iint \,\bar{\mathbf{I}}(a,b) \,- \,e{i2\pi(a\alpha + b\beta)} \,da\,db \Big]\,dx\,dy$$ ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: I appreciate your trying to help; I (hopefully) clarified the question above!

Comment: Sorry, beyond my current knowledge :-(.